# Utilisation of SDL_KEYDOWN

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

My program generates an image. I want to close the window by clicking on any key or by clicking with my pointer on the window cross. 
It works only by clicking on the cross (Use of SDL_QUIT) but not with SDL_KEYDOWN. I tried also with SDL_SPACE, SDL_KEYUP but the result is the same. 
So what am I missing in my code ?

I am using xcode.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL, *imageDeFond = NULL, *zozor = NULL;
    SDL_Rect positionFond, positionZozor;

    SDL_Event event; 

    int continuer = 1;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    ecran = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);

    imageDeFond = SDL_LoadBMP("lac_en_montagne.bmp");
    SDL_BlitSurface(imageDeFond, NULL, ecran, &positionFond);     

    SDL_Flip(ecran);

    while (continuer) 
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

        switch(event.type) 
        {
            case SDL_KEYDOWN: 
            {
                printf("use of SDL_KEYDOWN");
                continuer=0;
                break;

            }



            case SDL_QUIT: 
            {
                printf("use of SDL_QUIT");
                continuer = 0; 
                break;
            }

        }


    }


    SDL_FreeSurface(imageDeFond);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you sure that's the code you use, and window is focused when you press a key? Are you linking with `SDLmain`?

Comment: `#undef main` why? I suppose that's what breaks things for you. Remove that and link with `SDLmain`.